# Windows 2008 script error when mail server offline

Tags: windows, email, smtp

Everything works perfectly until our mail server goes offline. But when the mail server cannot be reached our scripting fails. When a user logs into the website th server sends a notice to admin by email. But if the mail server is offline that login fails and returns a server error.

We are using CDOSYS and using the local SMTP server to relay to our main mail server. The code is straightforward...

```
Set ObjSendMail = CreateObject("CDO.Message")   
ObjSendMail.Configuration.Fields.Item ("http://schemas.microsoft.com/cdo/configuration/sendusing") = 2 'Send the message using the network (SMTP over the network).
ObjSendMail.Configuration.Fields.Item ("http://schemas.microsoft.com/cdo/configuration/smtpserver") = artiscart_mail_server
ObjSendMail.Configuration.Fields.Item ("http://schemas.microsoft.com/cdo/configuration/smtpserverport") = 25
ObjSendMail.Configuration.Fields.Item ("http://schemas.microsoft.com/cdo/configuration/smtpusessl") = False 'Use SSL for the connection (True or False)
ObjSendMail.Configuration.Fields.Item ("http://schemas.microsoft.com/cdo/configuration/smtpconnectiontimeout") = 60    
ObjSendMail.Configuration.Fields.Update 
ObjSendMail.To = strEmail
ObjSendMail.Subject = "Login activity"
ObjSendMail.From = strEmail
ObjSendMail.TextBody = strEmailBody  
ObjSendMail.Send
Set ObjSendMail = Nothing
```

A similar thing happens when we send a newsletter and one of the emails is a dud. On Windows Server 2003 we had no problems whatsoever, but on Windows Server 2008 the same scripting fails.

Is there some way that I can configure the local SMTP server to ignore errors and move on?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To avoid all errors caused by mail server failure and bad email addresses, simply add this first line above the last line like so...

```
On Error Resume Next 
ObjSendMail.Send
```